# How does the communication between AngularJS and Play 2 works?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, url, playframework-2.0

Within the scope of a lecture at uni, we are currently trying to develop a Web Application using the Play 2 framework for the backend, AngularJS for the client side and Bootstrap for the overall appearance.

It is my first time using the Play and AngularJS framework and currently I am despairing about the communication between an AngularJS and Play controller. Actually, I would like to use my backend Play methods with the in routes defined URLs in my AngularJS controllers. The result of the Play methods which is a Query in my data base should be stored in an AngularJS array to be printed in the frontend via ng-repeat. In the following, please find my code for this.

The Method I would like to re-use in AngularJS is defined in a Play Controller:

```
package controllers; 

import ...

public class IListActions extends Controller {
    ...

    /* Read List */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public static Result getIList(int id) {
        IList ilist = IList.findById(id);
        return ilist == null ? notFound() :ok(Json.toJson(ilist));

    ...
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I declared in the Play routes:

```
GET   /api/getilist/:id                  controllers.IListActions.getIList(id: Integer)
```

So far, so good. We have tested the method and it is returning Json Objects nicely. We want to use /api/getilist/:id for the User id=1 in the beginning to display the list in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="liste in arrayListen">
    <div class="liste">
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{liste.name}}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span></button>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, what do we have to declare in our AngularJs controller, names `app.js`  to get this work. Long story short, we have tried to call `$http.get` for `/api/getilist/:id` but without any success.

I am sure, this should actually be no rocket science.

Comment: See http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2013/06/23/angularjs-and-play-framework/.